# How do I insert a span in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this sample:-

[link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VWddOe)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<p>
  width (10mm)
</p>
```

**CODE JS:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    //First bracket detection
});
```

The structure I want to obtain is the following (after document is ready):

```
<p>
    width <span>(10mm)</span>
</p>
```

I thought I could detect the first parenthesis in the string and then add a span.

Can you give me a simple example please how can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd recommend using jQuery's own [tutorial learning center](https://learn.jquery.com/).

Comment: Also a regex reference to pull out the part in parentheses: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: First, think of the logic. Second look up how to implement logic. Third, implement logic. Regular expressions may be a good start...

Comment: another option is `.split()` it is much easier to understand than using regex (for me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This will work in both cases*:-

*spaces/without spaces(example  `width (10mm)` or  `width(10mm)`):-*

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var string = $.trim($('p').text());
  string = string.replace(/\(([^)]+)\)/, "<span>$1</span>");
  $('p').html(string);
});
```

```css
span{
font-size:30px;
color:green;
background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  width (10mm)
</p>
```

Comment: Instead of the expected `width <span>(10mm)</span>` you are getting: `<span>width (10mm)</span>`

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var $p = $("p");
    var text = $p.text().trim();
    text = text.split(" ");
    text = text[0] + "<span>" + text[1] + "</span>";
    $p.text(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $p = $('p'),
    text = $p.text().trim(),
    replaceWith = text.replace(/\(.+\)/, '<span>$&</span>');
       
$p.html(replaceWith)
```

```css
span {color: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>width (10mm)</p>
```